# How to calculate html table column data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a Dynamically created HTML table, when page loads I am creating the first row having following columns `ItemName`,`I Code`,`MRP`,`Price`,`UnitQty`,`Disc%`,`DiscAmt`,`Gst%`,`GstAmt` and `TotalAmt`

`ItemName` is autocomplete field, So user is selecting item name by typeing and when user focus out I am populating some respective fields ,When user Types inside `UnitQty` field I am calculating some values and populating according to that in respective fields on `keyup` event all this is happening in HTML table

outside the tabel I have a Input Field `SubTotal` which is I am getting with Some calculation i.e `price * UnitQty` so for respective table row There is a Total Amt column where I have to populate `(price * UnitQty) +GstAmt +DiscAmt` but currently I am populating `price * UnitQty` I will do that later

**What My issue is**

So below is a `subTotal` Input field where I am populating  `price * UnitQty` of each row so I am storing the values in global variable and then adding the current variable into that but when I type suppose 2 and price is 100 it equals to 200 then I am removing 2 and writing 2 at that time it is adding the previous 200 and current 300 and populating 500 I know this is because of `keyup` it is adding previous value also but that's not correct

There is no column for subtotal in HTML table that's why I am storing it in a variable

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2) {
  const fixed = parseFloat(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [float, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+float)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}


$(document).ready(function() {


  var tableData = {};
  var tabledata = {
    "ALMOND CHBAR~2402": {
      "itemName": "ALMOND CHBAR",
      "itemCode": "2402",
      "costPrice": 20.0,
      "gstPercentage": 14.5,
      "unitCode": "NOS",
      "mrp": 30.0
    },
    "A BR SB EX~333": {
      "itemName": "A BR SB EX",
      "itemCode": "333",
      "costPrice": 1.0,
      "gstPercentage": 0.0,
      "unitCode": "NOS",
      "mrp": 1.0
    }
  }

  populateData(tabledata)

  function rowappend(tbody) {

    const markup =
      `<tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
           <td><input type="tel"  id="purRatetd"  class="form-control commantd"name="purRatetd"></td>
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange" name="unitQtytd">
           </td>
                         
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commanChange" name="discPercentagetd" value="0.00">
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td> 
           <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
           <input type="hidden" name="unittd" id="unittd" class="form-control commantd">
           <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn" ></i></td>
           
         </tr>`

    $(tbody).append(markup);
    setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);

    var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(tableData);
    $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().autocomplete({
      source: autoCompleteData,
      autoSelectFirst: true,
      autoFocus: true

    }).data('tableData', tableData);


  }


  function getValues(row) {
    const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()

    var data = $('[name=itemNametd]', row).data('tableData');
    const value = data[search];

    if (value) {
      CostPrice = value.costPrice;
      $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").val(value.itemCode);
      $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val(format(value.mrp));
      $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val(format(CostPrice));
      $(row).find("[name=unittd]").val(value.unitCode);
      $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val(value.gstPercentage);
      $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();
    }

  }


  $(document).on("keyup", "[name=purRatetd]", function(e) {
    const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
    var unitQuantity = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val();

    var purchaseRate = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val();
    var mrp = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val();
    totalAmount = (parseFloat(unitQuantity) * parseFloat(purchaseRate)) || 0;

    $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val(format(totalAmount));

  });
  var subTotalAmt = 0;
  $(document).on("keyup", "[name=unitQtytd]", function(e) {

    const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
    unitQuantity = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val();

    purchaseRate = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val();
    mrp = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val();
    totalAmount = (parseFloat(unitQuantity) * parseFloat(purchaseRate)) || 0;

    subTotalAmt += totalAmount || 0

    $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val(format(totalAmount));
    $("#subTotalInput").val(format(subTotalAmt));
  });


  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement

    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keycode == '13') {
      if (!$(event.target).val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
      const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
      if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {
        if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
          rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)
        }
      }
    }

  });

  $(document).on("focusout", "[name=itemNametd]", function(e) {
    const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
    getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
  });

  function populateData(data) {
    tableData = Object.assign({}, data);
    var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(data);
    rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'));


  }




});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row tableGrn" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
        <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">I Code</th>
        <th id="mrpth" class="commanth">MRP</th>
        <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Price</th>
        <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
        <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc %</th>
        <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
        <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">GST %</th>
        <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">GST Amt</th>
        <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amt</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="subTotalInput">Sub Total</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="subTotalInput" id="subTotalInput" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note-:** Please don't get confused by TotalAmt column that one is for other usage which I will do by adding all the amounts

For now I have been stuck in calculating subTotal row wise and populate in a Input field

On press of `enter` at `Disc%` it will create a new row

Comment: Can you reproduce just the actual issue with a **minimal** example?  There's way too much unrelated code.

Comment: It *looks like* you are simply not resetting `subTotalAmt`.  To fix this, rather than add each row as it changes, just recalculate the whole column.  Unless you have 10,000+ rows (which is a bad idea anyway), you won't notice any performance issues.

Comment: @freedomn-m yup I am not resetting the `subtotalAmt`  I don't know how to do that

Comment: If you add to the sub total each time a value changes then you need to remove the old value first (so you need to store the old value, either in a hidden field or in a `data-` attribute) **or** don't keep a running total in memory and just recalculate all the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace your code with below code

```
$(document).on("keyup", "[name=purRatetd],[name=unitQtytd]", function(e) {
    var unitQuantity = $(this).closest('tr').find("[name=unitQtytd]").val();
    var purchaseRate = $(this).closest('tr').find("[name=purRatetd]").val();
    var unitQuantity = unitQuantity ? unitQuantity : 1;
    var mrp = $(this).closest('tr').find("[name=mrptd]").val();
    totalAmount = (parseFloat(unitQuantity) * parseFloat(purchaseRate));
    $(this).closest('tr').find("[name=totalAmttd]").val(totalAmount);
    var subTotal = 0;
    $("[name=totalAmttd]").each(function(){
        var curVal = parseFloat($(this).val());
        if(curVal){
            subTotal = curVal + subTotal;
        }
    });
    $("#subTotalInput").val(subTotal);
});
```

N:B - you are using id in input fields which will repeat again and again after apending so avoid using id and name...In entire code you can use class instead of name or id......class name can be same but id and name can't be same in multiple fields

Comment: You are saying to store product of price and Unit qty into hidden Field?

Comment: Think if someone will change the value by clicking right click then it will be a problem and this is not the professional behaviour so better on change hit a ajax request with the product id and quantity then calculate everything in server  in final just render the value in client

Comment: you are saying when user selects any itemname that time I should call an AJAX and call data for that item  which is selected?

Comment: no when changing the quantity that time you need to call ajax request parameter will be product id and product quantity ......then in server validate everything whether it's exceeding maximum quantity or not then take the product price from product id through query then multiply product price with quantity .....in response you will get the calculated amount just render in client side

Comment: but from server side it will be very complex there are so many calculations which is going on ,suppose user selects an item name I am populating the respective data the if in same row if user wants to change unitQty then ehat should I do, I have to do it on client side only

Comment: ok if you want to do it in client side then the only solution is hidden field and each time take value from hidden field only.....but rememeber if someone will change that value from hidden through console then the calulation will be wrong

Comment: While all very interesting - this doesn't appear to be addressing the problem described in the question.  In that adding up totals gets the same total added multiple times.

Comment: hey please check the chat I have shared the screenshot